# PhpStorm Laravel artisan Mamp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm, laravel-artisan

I'm learning PHP and wanted to work with Laravel, by doing so i follow tutorials and the guy explaining it uses artisan commands. 
However I looked it up on how to add such commands but every time i go to command line tool support it gives me this error

> Problem
>   Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 2: Content is not allowed in prolog..

Command

```
php.exe D:\Websites\untitled\artisan list --format=xml
```

Output

> Warning: require(D:\Websites\untitled\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Websites\untitled\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\Websites\untitled\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Websites\untitled\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

So i removed that project and installed Laravel again using "composer project" 
and trying to add the artisan again doesn't work again with this fresh start.

Am I missing something? Or did I forgot something to do?

I hope someone can help me since I'm still a beginner and this would be a good learning school

Greetings
Ditger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run composer install before using php artisan:
`composer install`

Comment: That error is pretty self explanatory - you need to enable the mbstring extension (hint: it's most likely commented out in your php.ini).